# crypto.hkdfSync is not function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am using Node JS crypto library in my chrome Extension, As a Javascript file it is working fine. But when I run it as extension file, I am getting crypto.hkdfSync is not function.
I am using typescript for extension code.

Comment: [`crypto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/crypto_property) in your extension isn't the same as [`crypto`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) in Node.js

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.